# An ordered basis can be viewed as a linear isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $E$ be a vector space. What is the meaning of the following sentence:

An ordered basis on $E$ can be viewed as a linear isomorphism 
$$p:\mathbb R^k\to E$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\{ e_1, \ldots, e_k \}$ is an ordered basis for $E$, then define $p$ by
$$p(x_1, \ldots, x_n) = x_1e_1 + \cdots x_ke_k$$
You can check that this is an isomorphism of vector spaces by using the fact that $\{e_1, \ldots, e_k \}$ is a basis.

Conversely, if $p : \mathbb{R}^k \to E$ is an isomorphism, then you can check that the images of the standard basis vectors in $\mathbb{R}^k$ form a basis for $E$.